# Speed up a VBA Replace-loop possible or use other method?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, replace

I have a small VBA Loop but it takes over 2-3 minute to finish, any idea how I can speed up/rewrite it that it will be faster?

The Range "Replace Names" is a List of 500 names of named areas in "Data".
The for loop searches for the one that matches the name in "Data" and replaces the one with the name from "Source". This also works fine, but it takes a while. Is there a faster method?

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each ID_name In wsSupport.Range("ReplaceNames")
        wsCheck.Range("Data").Replace ID_name, wsSource.Range(ID_name), xlWhole

    Next

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Write your range to an array and loop through there - much faster!

Comment: Hi Dean, tnak you. I tried it, but it took nearly the same time, I think the big time waster is the replacement method itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might benefit from this valuable piece of text:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/

So in your case the Code could somewhat look like this:

```
Dim arrData as Variant, arrSource as Variant, k as long
arrData = wsCheck.Range("Data").value2 'this creates a two-dimensional array with rows on the first and columns on the second index
arrSource = wsSource.Range(...).value2

'loop through rows I suppose
for k = LBound(arrData,1) to UBound(arrData,1)
    if arrData(k, yourColumn) = ... then
        arrData(k, yourColumn) = arrSource(rowhere, columnhere)
    endif   
next k

wscheck.range("Data") = arrData
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it, but it took nearly the same time, I think the big time waster is the replacement method itself

Comment: There is no usage of the replacement method when working with arrays like in this example. Generally working with arrays should be considerably faster, as it doesn't loop through the worksheet itself, but a copy of the contents which are stored in a variable.

Comment: shouldn't that last line read `wscheck.range("Data").Value2 = arrData`

Comment: For consistency purposes you are right, I guess. However, without further testing I would assume that when pasting back to the sheet there should be no measurable difference between using .value ([which is the standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.range.value)) and .value2.

Comment: but I have to find the corresponding cell in the sheet("Check") first, because it is somewhere in the document (always differently structured). And then I tried the .find and .replace method, both take a very long time. i don't understand how I can use an array if I don't know the target cell where something will be replaced? sorry, I used the first al arrays.

Comment: Could you provide some more information about the structure of your sheet?

Comment: I have got it!!! thank you very much for your ideas! this helped me!! T have extended it a little bit under the code, if you see mistakes please let me know!!

Answer (score 0):

Its working now!!!
If you see mistakes let me know!

```
Dim arrData As Variant, arrSource As Variant, arrNames As Variant, k As Long

arrData = wsChecklist.Range("Checklist").Value2 'this creates a two-dimensional array with rows on the first and columns on the second index
arrSource = wsSupport.Range("ReplaceNames").Value2
arrNames = wsNia.Range("D1:D1000").Value2

'loop through rows I suppose
For k = LBound(arrData, 1) To UBound(arrData, 1)
For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)

'    If UCase(arrData(k, j)) = UCase(arrSource(x, 1)) Then
    If UCase(arrSource(x, 1)) = UCase(arrData(k, j)) Then

    For i = 1 To 1000
            Name1 = wsNia.Cells(i, 2)
            Name2 = wsNia.Cells(i, 3)
            Name = Name1 & "_" & Name2

        If UCase(arrData(k, j)) = UCase(Name) Then
                arrData(k, j) = arrNames(i, 1)
                x = x + 1
                k = 1
                j = 1
                i = 1

            Exit For
        End If


Next i

    End If

If k > 2900 And x < 265 Then
    x = x + 1
    j = 1
    k = 1
End If

Next j
Next k

wsChecklist.Range("Checklist").Value2 = arrData
```

Comment: It would be logical to use your array arrNames instead of `wsNia.Cells(i,2) etc.`